# How can I increment numbers in a list without creating a new list?

Tags: python

How to increase each number of the list by 7 in python without creating a new list ? I mean each of the original numbers are increased by 7 .

for example we have this list :

```
list=[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    myList[i] = myList[i]+7
```

As requested, this iterates through the list and sums 7 to each element. To test that it's the same list, you can use `id(myList)` before and after and it should yield the same id.

Comment: Thank you , but this code without using a new list right ?

Comment: It uses the same list, I changed the name from list to myList because list is a function name used by Python.

Comment: You are welcome! If you found this useful don't forget to mark this answer as the solution.